# No overload for method 'HealthcareuserBL' takes '13' arguments

Tags: c#

I am getting error like this in register.cs i am new to c#

```
BL.HealthcareuserBL obj = new BL.HealthcareuserBL(Emailid, password, Dateofbirth,
                                                  Repassword, Name, Gender, 
                                                  Address, Country, City, 
                                                  Postalcode, Mobileno, Phoneno, 
                                                  State);
obj.Emailid = txtemailid.Text;
obj.password = txtpassword.Text;
obj.Repassword = txtconfirmpassword.Text;
obj.Name = txtname.Text;
obj.Dateofbirth = Convert.ToString(txtdataofbirth.Text);
obj.Gender = ddlgender.SelectedItem;
obj.Address = txtaddress.Text;
obj.Country = ddlcountry.SelectedItem;
obj.State = ddlstate.SelectedItem;
obj.City = txtcity.Text;
obj.Postalcode = Convert.ToString(txtcity.Text);
obj.Mobileno = Convert.ToString(txmobileno.Text);
obj.Phoneno = Convert.ToString(txtphoneno.Text);
```

this line showing error

```
BL.HealthcareuserBL obj = new BL.HealthcareuserBL(Emailid, password, Dateofbirth,
                                                  Repassword, Name, Gender, 
                                                  Address, Country, City, 
                                                  Postalcode, Mobileno, Phoneno, 
                                                  State);
```

Like 
No overload for method 'HealthcareuserBL' takes '13' arguments

now think my question is clear BUt it is true question

Comment: If you want to add details to your question, edit your question and not the answers others have given...

Comment: sorry i had Confused now you understand my question

Comment: read what ppl wrote; you definitely must describe what you are using or trying to achive, most notably, how does `HealthcareuserBL` look like

Answer (score 3):

That's because there is no overload visible to the compiler that takes 13 arguments, exactly like the compiler complains.

For more information, we need more information: What is `HealthcareuserBL`? What are you trying to achive?

Answer (score 1):

<del>I don't think that is valid syntax. As far as I can see, you are putting the property names inside the constructor but also assign values to them afterwards.</del> Most likely `HealthcareuserBL` doesn't have a constructor with arguments, so your code should look like this:

```
BL.HealthcareuserBL obj = new BL.HealthcareuserBL();
obj.Emailid = txtemailid.Text;
// snip
obj.Phoneno = Convert.ToString(txtphoneno.Text);
```

Comment: See his other (closed) post. It declares those variables. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304412/no-overload-for-method-healthcareuserbl-takes-13-arguments)

Comment: I see. But this doesn't change anything. It just declares them, because he doesn't seem to understand the syntax. My assumption is still valid.

Comment: True, I remember forced initialization in c# :)

Answer (score 0):

How does the constructor of `HealthcareuserBL` look like? But why in the world are you passing in all parameters to it if you set them directly on the object later anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it this way.. If the members are correct...

```
BL.HealthcareuserBL obj = new BL.HealthcareuserBL
{
        Emailid = txtemailid.Text,
        password = txtpassword.Text,
        Repassword = txtconfirmpassword.Text,
        Name = txtname.Text,
        Dateofbirth = Convert.ToString(txtdataofbirth.Text),
        Gender = ddlgender.SelectedItem,
        Address = txtaddress.Text,
        Country = ddlcountry.SelectedItem,
        State = ddlstate.SelectedItem,
        City = txtcity.Text,
        Postalcode = Convert.ToString(txtcity.Text),
        Mobileno = Convert.ToString(txmobileno.Text),
        Phoneno = Convert.ToString(txtphoneno.Text),
}
```